# Why is firefox showing me the slideshow, but chrome isn't?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

any idea why this slideshow does work in Firefox, but not in Chrome?(Haven't tested in IE) Hope someone can help!

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
  margin:50px auto;
  width:60em;
  height:18em;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:0.4em solid;
  border-color: black;
  position:relative;
}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
}
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/Red.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/rose.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/White.jpeg" alt="">
    <img class='photo'  src="Images/rose.jpeg" alt="">      
</div>
```

Comment: Chrome (still) uses `-webkit-animation` and `@-webkit-keyframes`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol could you post the solution as an Answer so he can select it as the Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is lagging behind a bit with this particular one - not sure why, really.

As shown on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), Chrome requires the `-webkit-` prefix on all animation-related properties, as well as `@-webkit-keyframes`.

Add these, and it should all work fine. It's kind of annoying to have to duplicate everything just for Chrome, but oh well...

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideshow {
  margin:50px auto;
  width:60em;
  height:18em;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:0.4em solid;
  border-color: black;
  position:relative;
}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  -webkit-animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
}
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 
@-webkit-keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses different syntex:

```
@-webkit-keyframes
-webkit-animation
-webkit-animation-delay
```